# How to carry on with original action after preventing default in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have two buttons: "next" and "back". I assign clicks to the them:

```
jQuery( "#edit-next" ).click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    trackEvent("next");
    // MISSING CODE HERE?
});

jQuery( "#edit-back" ).click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    trackEvent("back");
    // MISSING CODE HERE?
});
```

I need to add the preventDefault, as currently when the person presses next or back, it simply doesn't register the "trackEvent" code in time. So my problem is adding the right line of code where I said MISSING CODE HERE. The line must basically "undo" the preventDefault and result in the back and next buttons being clicked as they  would have had I not added preventDefault.

How do I do that?

Comment: I don't see why _it simply doesn't register the "trackEvent" code in time_. Does `trackEvent` have asynchronous code?

Comment: It used to have google's asynchronous tracking code, but now it just does an ajax call. Which I assume is asynchronous right. So yes, I think that is what is causing it.

Comment: What is the default action of the buttons? Submitting a form?

Comment: @coderama you can use flag (to check whether it is user click or your second click) and trigger `click` again on ajax success

Comment: Yes, the default action is to submit a form

Comment: @coderama so, once again, you are stuck with preventing default and sending ajax request on first click and executing default on second artificial click.

Comment: Or ajaxing the form in the trackevent succes handler